# How to check if Parcelable is NULL

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I am working on receiving parcelable objects in the MainActiviy. I have tried using

```
 if((Task)getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable(Create.TASK_KEY) != null)
```

to check before trying to get a Parcelable. Unfortunately, this crashes the application with the null pointer exception. How can I check to make sure a parcelable is available before trying to retrieve it?

Comment: If this is crashing with an NPE, that means either `getIntent()` or `getExtras()` returned `null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use

```
  if (getIntent().hasExtra(Create.TASK_KEY)) {

  }
```

it returns true only if the internal bundle is not null and you have an object with the key provided as parameter

as correctly pointed out from @kcoppock you could also put a null object in the bundle.

```
  Task task = null;
  if ((task = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(Create.TASK_KEY)) != null) {
     // do something with task
  }
```

Comment: Although this doesn't technically ensure the value is non-null, for example, if the Intent had been populated with: `intent.putExtra(Create.TASK_KEY, null);`.

Comment: you cannot put null extra as it creates ambiguity with the putExtra methods

Comment: @kcoppock thanks for pointing it out. I was not aware that one could put null object. I edited my answer. Any thoughts ?

Comment: @giorashc There's nothing in the code that prevents that case. You probably *shouldn't* do it, but it can be done. (e.g. you could do `putExtra("key", (String) null);` to avoid ambiguity)

Answer (score 2):

I think that getExtras is returning null value, so your code results in NullPointerException. Try checking extras for null value too:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null && extras.getParcelable(Create.TASK_KEY) != null) {
    ...
}
```